# How to sync printing of characters with sound?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to emulate what an old manual typewriter does when printing what is being typed on a web page. I want to develop JavaScript functions to pass it a string, and it would print out each character with a delay, and the sound file synced with each letter.

I'm new to JavaScript. What is the preferred method to do this? Should I be looking at jQuery for this? Or is this something simple to do?

I've seen problems with sound files being triggered like this on some web browsers, is there an audio file format which is best for this sort of thing?

I've found this, but the problem is, it doesn't work on all web browsers:
https://rawgit.com/mehaase/js-typewriter/master/example3-typewriter/index.html

Comment: Try to think a bit about what you are trying to do, break the problem down, search the internet for each part, try to implement it, then if you have issues, come ask about them here! SO isn't the best place to ask such broad questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
// The delay between each keystroke
var delay = 300;
 
// The typewriter sound file url
var clickURL = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/halimb/res/6ffa798d/typewriter.wav";
 
// Get a reference to the container div
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var sampleString = "Hello world!";
 
//get a reference to the start button and typewrite onclick
var start = document.getElementById("btn");
start.onclick = function() { typewrite( sampleString ); };
 
function typewrite( str ) {
    var i = 0;
    container.innerHTML = "";
    type();
 
    function type() {
        var click = new Audio( clickURL );
        // This is triggered when the browser has enough of the file to play through
        click.oncanplaythrough = function() {
            click.play();
            // Add the character to the container div
            container.innerHTML += str[i];
            i++;
            if(i < str.length) {
                window.setTimeout(type, delay);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

```css
* {
 font-family: Courier;
 font-size: 32px;
}

.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" id="btn">Start</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Update: on Safari. It seems the audio has to be triggered by a user event (e.g: onclick..), so I added a button, and made the typewriter start onclick.

The downside is that there's no way to pre-load the audio file, Safari make a server request and downloads the audio each time it is played. the only (dirty) way I could think of to overcome this is to provide a data URI instead of the audioURL.. you can try that if the playback speed really matters (this can be helpful: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/)

Comment: Nice! Do you have any idea why this works on Google Chrome/Mac, but it doesn't work on Safari/Mac? There is no sound.

Comment: I read a suggest elsewhere, that using ogg instead of wav files for Safari might work better? You have any thoughts on that?

Comment: it's actually the opposite, support for ogg is limited, wav files are better for cross browser support (except for IE). here's a table showing supported formats on different browsers: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats

Comment: Thanks. What about mobile, I thought I read someplace that ogg was needed for mobile, like on the iPhone?

Comment: Perhaps this is the answer for audio?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API

Comment: I don't know about mobile, as for the Web Audio API it sure is richer and more powerful however since it's at a lower level, it will require more code to set up, it's up to you to choose whatever suits you best ;)